# Null Pointer When Passing object to new activity through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ixmlserializable

So I have read through many questions on this site (and others), and I cannot find a working solution for my code so I figure the next step is to post it on here. I am making a maze game. I have a generating activity and a playing activity, and I am trying to pass the generated Maze object to the PlayActivity. Maze is serializable, but when I try to get the maze from my intent in PlayActivity it is returning a null pointer exception. Any thoughts would be wonderful.

```
Maze:
public class Maze implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

And then GeneratingActivity:

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(this , PlayActivity.class);
playIntent.putExtra("MadeMaze" , maze);
startActivity(playIntent);
```

And finally PlayActivity:

```
maze = (Maze) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MadeMaze");
System.out.print(maze.mazecells.toString());
System.out.print("here");
```

I know someone will probably suggest using Parcelable, but my Maze class has so many data fields it doesn't quite seem worth it (unless someone has good reason otherwise).

EDIT: Here's the log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{edu.wm.cs.cs301.jesavino/edu.wm.cs.cs301.jesavino.UI.PlayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at edu.wm.cs.cs301.jesavino.UI.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:36)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-20 21:46:37.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1940):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post logcat error here

Comment: Did you check to make sure maze.mazecells isn't null?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print(maze.toString()) should not be null, check it

Comment: You are correct, Maze is not null, it is specifically the mazecells that is null. But that is set (tested) in GeneratingActivity, so I'm confused as to why that one field will not transfer

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Bundle

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(this , PlayActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("MadeMaze", maze);
playIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(playIntent);
```

and in PlayActivity

```
 maze = (Maze) getIntent().getExtra().getSerializable("MadeMaze");
```

Answer (score 0):

try implement Parcelable in your Maze class。

Serializable is not well supported by Android, and you should use Parcelable first when you try to sending data between android context.

Comment: `Serializeable` is supported but slower than `Parcelable`

Comment: I am fine with slower, since it looks like Parcelable will be a lot more work due to the number of attributes I would have to add in Maze